# Is there any ORM available which will create table on the fly and make insert for MySql/MariaDB

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

I can use below code which will insert a record in pre-defined table for MySql/MariaDB.

```
 // Insert some data
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (some_field) VALUES (@p)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", "Hello world");
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Is there any ORM or utility nuget available which will create the table on the fly and insert C# object without any INSERT, is ORM also available something like this,

```
foreach (var obj in Messages)
        {
            db.Insert(obj);
        }
```

Comment: What you want is a migrator. [FluentMigrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/) which is used on [Serenity](https://github.com/volkanceylan/Serenity) support MySQL, it can even create the database from scratch (so all you need to deploy is the .dll, on first run it will take care of creating the DB, updating the schema if necessary etc).

Comment: "Creating a table on the fly" is _generally_ a misuse of RDBMS.